# Proving surjectivity of a strictly monotone function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function with $|f'(x)|<M$ for all $x$. Then I want to show that there exists an $a>0$ such that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=x+af(x)$ is a bijection with differentiable inverse.

For $a<1/M$ I have shown that it is strictly monotone, which implies it's injective and that it has a differentiable inverse. How can I show that is surjective?

Comment: please provide solution for injectivity...I tried solving but I did the same as Kim Jong un ...I don't know how it proves injectivity...it doesn't show x=y .

Answer (score 2):

Choose a positive $a<{1\over M}$. Then $m:=1-aM>0$. Since
$$g'(x)=1+af'(x)>1-a M=m\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)$$
the function  $g$ is monotonically increasing, hence injective on ${\mathbb R}$. Furthermore
$$g(x)=g(0)+\int_0^x g'(t)\>dt>g(0)+mx\to\infty\qquad(x\to\infty)\ ,$$
and similarly $\lim_{x\to-\infty}g(x)=-\infty$. It follows that $g$ maps ${\mathbb R}$ bijectively onto ${\mathbb R}$. As $g'(x)>0$ for all $x$ the inverse map $\>g^{-1}\!\!:\>{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R}$ is $C^1$ again.

Answer (score 1):

By [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) the condition $|f'(x)|<M$ implies $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is bounded. So you know that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}x+af(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}x+ax\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty}x(a+\frac{f(x)}{x})=\mp \infty$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}g(x)=\pm \infty$$

But $g$ is contionous, so by [Intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) $g$ is surjective.

Comment: But $f$ is not necessarily bounded. However, we know that $g'(x)\ge 1-\frac aM$ is bounded away from $0$ ...

Comment: @ Hagen: completely agree with you. For example, $f(x)=x$ has $|f'|=1$ but $f$ isn't bounded.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.

Comment: @ agha: Do you use $a<\frac{1}{M}$ somewhere?

Comment: No, I prove only that $f$ is surjection, not bijection.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken but I think that to make the limit $\lim_{x->\infty}x(a+f(x)/x)=\mp\infty$ works you need to make sure that $a+f(x)/x$ doesn't change sign. And for that, you need to impose something on $a$. $a<\frac{1}{M}$ works for my proof below. I wonder if that will also work with yours.

Comment: Plus, I think you might need to add $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is bounded * for large $|x|$ * because otherwise the statement is false. For example, consider $f(x)=\cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another look at surjectivity: suppose $y>x$ is such that $g(x)=g(y)$. Then
$$
y+af(y)=x+af(x)\implies(y-x)=a(f(x)-f(y))=a(x-y)f'(z)
$$
for some $z\in(x,y)$. Taking absolute values of both sides:
$$
|y-x|=a|y-x||f'(z)|\implies 1=a|f'(z)|.
$$
But $a|f'(z)|<\frac{1}{M}M=1$ so you have the desired contradiction.

Comment: If I understood correctly this is an argument about the injectivity not surjectivity though.

Comment: Does this proves injectivity? I need proof for injectivity...