# Proving $f(x)=x+ϵg(x)$ is onto if $ϵ$ is small enough

Tags: calculus, functions

Problem: Suppose $g$ is a real function on $\mathbb{R}$ with bounded derivative $|g′|<M$. Fix $\epsilon>0$, and define $f(x)=x+ϵg(x)$. Prove that $f$ is onto if $ϵ$ is small enough.

I got that $f'(x) = 1 + \epsilon g'(x)$ and for $ \epsilon < 1/M$, $f'(x) > 0$ $ \forall$ $ x$.

So f is monotonically increasing.

f(0) < 1 and f(2) > 1

Not sure how to proceed to show that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910091/proving-surjectivity-of-a-strictly-monotone-function